Playwright - how to locate browser path at run-time
I'm trying to get the path of the browser's executable path inside my test.
I have to get that path in order to add a specific browser policy (Chromium) at the beginning of the test.

Fortunately Playwright has a built-In method executablePath() for that:
test("my test", async ({ browser, page }) => {
  await page.goto("/");
  browser.browserType().executablePath()
});

